# What is the relationship between some measure of reputation on our site and statistical prowess?

Tags: discussion, questions

There is first a question within this question, and, that is "Where should I be posing the question?"

There are certainly people on this site with marvelous minds. The second question, the primary one, relates to the fact that it's nice to have a reputation on Cross Validated, and, many of us, especially those in the "leagues" with 200+ reputations have considerable knowledge of things statistical.

Is there then some measure of reputation, e.g. quarterly ranking, on Cross Validated that is well correlated to some measure of ability to use statistics, e.g., educational level in statistics?

Now the examples (the e.g.'s) I used are somewhat arbitrary, and in the extreme I am asking something along the lines of determining what a "pseudo-PhD" in Cross-Validation might be.

Comment: If you take the narrow sense of "reputation" as being total points, it might help to understand that it compresses many variables onto a single scale, including activities to maintain the site, quality and number of questions, giving of bounties, and pure number of answers.  As such, it is practically worthless--and maybe even deceptive--as a measure of any aspect of statistical capabilities.  If you take "reputation" in a wider sense as comprising all the statistics about an individual's activity, then *possibly* some rough sense of their capabilities can be gleaned from those.

Comment: I really don't think there's much of a reliable relationship; there's some relationship because obviously it's easier for a skilled person to write an upvoted answer than an unskilled one but the relationship may be very weak -- it's possible to accumulate a large amount of reputation through answering a lot of questions while armed with mediocre skills; on the other hand a lot of highly skilled and knowledgeable people on site have low reputations, because they don't spend much time here.

Comment: On the other hand some of the information available can be a bit more informative, by removing the raw effect of answering a lot -- reputation per answer (though this can be a bit noisy - actual upvotes per answer will be better, if harder to get) , proportion of accepted answers, and so on. If you really want to look at total contributions rather than relative ones, choose something that's harder to get than upvotes -- number of "Good Answers" may be a semi- useful measure for example.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of one asked four years ago by Michael Chernick at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1218.  Related threads include http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2107 concerning the value of CV participation in job hunting.

Comment: @whuber Macro's criterion (number of silver badges) would suit me well for the same reason he suggested it but I don't know that it's all that reliable a measure.

Comment: @Glen_b Maybe--after subtracting the badges for site participation. That count is a proxy for the number of very highly upvoted posts, with a component for speedy answers. When I evaluate people on unfamiliar sites in order to ascertain who knows their stuff and can communicate it well, I look for quality and consistency as measured by relatively high votes per answer, high acceptance rate per answer, extremely few posts with zero or negative net votes, a broad range of tags (without undue specialization in any one), and more than one very highly voted post. E.g., cardinal, chl, glen_b.

Comment: Yes, those criteria  collectively come close to conveying some sense of skill (ah, an accidental alliteration)

Comment: Hey. How about actually using the data on the CV site to figure this out? There is lots of it. Some people give their educational level well enough to dope out what a rep means, and if anyone can figure this out, GUESS WHO THAT IS!

Comment: Some have tried. There's too much noise: you have to factor in degree of activity, time elapsed since joining, effects of all non-answer forms of reputation, and so on. You would also have to control for the thousands of different tags (it's easier to get reputation in some tags and harder in others), the time of day a question was answered, how many people were active on the site shortly thereafter, whether a post was promoted, etc.  Even then you wouldn't be measuring statistical skill, but some combination of knowledge, ability to write and illustrate, perseverance, and luck.

Comment: @Glen_b By the criteria you have outlined, answering a lot - reputation per answer - actual upvotes, and so on - I would probably rate as an absolute dummy. But, I have only been active this last quarter of a year, and my objective has been largely to learn, not to acquire reputation necessarily. That means that I have answered a lot of dumb questions from people who do not know as much as I do overall, but, they do ask questions about things I have to look up. If all I want to do was impress people, then I would ask and answer questions most people wouldn't have a clue about.

Comment: The point I was trying to get at before was that I don't think "answering a lot" (and things that depend on that most heavily) indicates anything of much value. Relative measures like reputation per answer (especially if they relate to more than a handful of answers) is more of an indication. I agree with the criteria whuber indicates. But it's hard to compare newer users with people who have been answering for years because it can take a while to learn what works for the site -- even if you're used to answering questions in other fora.

Comment: @whuber The reward system we have is very quantitative, lots and lots of numbers in a profile. You may deprecate this, but frankly, compared to getting a grade in a statistics course, it is probably rather more information rich. In fact, my participation on this site brings back memories of my schooling more than anything else I have done recently. And when I was studying at the undergraduate level, many years ago, much of what I did were "reading courses" because I frankly did not belong in a classroom. So, there is something very familiar about this site, for me.

Comment: @Glen_b Why don't you combine your comments into a single answer?

Comment: The short answer is evidently very weak at best. In addition to points excellently made, I add: please don't underestimate what reputation measures any more than you should overestimate it. Some reputation here is earned with much difficulty trying to help confused people asking not very good questions. Those people often don't even accept answers; the answers may not be general or good enough to gain many upvotes; they may even be pedestrian by the highest standards because they just give banal or basic advice. But the effort is all intended to help, if only the people asking the questions.

Comment: Hinting darkly that many reputations are inflated and not to be taken that seriously isn't positive. It's true, but it's also unduly disparaging to those who just want to help build and maintain the site.

Comment: @Nick Many reputations are hard earned from  giving valuable advice, and well-deserved, so much is clear (indeed many high-value contributors have a much lower reputation than their contributions deserve).  The difficulty is in trying to go the other way -- to associate some particular reputation with some level of attainment in statistical understanding (see the question's proposal of some level of reputation as a "pseudo-PhD"). If someone were compare me to cardinal on reputation alone, they'd be led to *entirely* the wrong conclusion -- a broader set of measures would lead to a better sense

Comment: There are possibly a few people with high reputations who have gotten them without knowing that much. There are also some PhD's who have gotten them without knowing much. They could even be the same people. I am not sure that would even modify a correlation between rate of accrual of reputation and educational level.

Comment: @Carl you may have something of a point there -- that there's something of the same potential for misjudging knowledge if all you know is that someone has a PhD. But I don't think the point here is that you *can't* make any judgement, only to beware using reputation by itself, because it's at least as much a reflection of enthusiasm as knowledge. If you want to get a sense of how knowledgeable someone is there's a lot more information available, and using it can lead to a considerably more robust judgement. It might be interesting to attempt to construct some reasonable measure.

Comment: To that end, several of [Martijn Pieters' data.SE queries](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/5824/martijn-pieters) seem to be aiming at getting at different aspects of this kind of measure.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes. Let us consider the the statements "Carl is a statistician," versus "Carl is not a statistician." Note, Carl doesn't care what he is, as a person, with respect to things statistical, but he is curious as to how much of a statistical ladder he has yet to climb.  Quite a bit, I think. So asking what reputation is worth in real world terms is intensely interesting. I know someone (unnamed here) who is using this site to train for a job, and this site is useful to some. So the question as to CV's "currency conversion" as it were is a practical one.

Comment: The site is certainly useful to many of us (myself included) as one of a number of learning tools.

Comment: @Carl It's difficult to say what value anybody outside CV places on CV reputation. I can believe anything from a record of posting lucid and penetrating answers helping a job application a little to it being regarded totally negatively in some universities, where only papers in top journals and/or top conferences are of interest (and any dissipation of energy elsewhere is a distraction at best). My first approximation is that it's a game you play because you find it challenging and rewarding (as many do with chess, bridge, sudoku, ....) and hope that some others benefit too.

Comment: @NickCox For myself, I cannot think of a better way of checking things to include in a journal article than posting a question here. Getting beaten up for half-baked language, and incorrect ideas is quite instructive, and the feedback cycle is minutes compared to months for a journal.

Comment: @Carl Perhaps, but how much reputation gain do you get for posting a lousy question? You're flagging a feature of CV that others will appreciate too, but I'd rather people post good questions in the first instance!

Comment: @NickCox Actually, things that confuse me have answers that are either publishable by themselves or in the direction of clarification of data for publication, and if they were simple, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: @Carl Me too! But I don't see what that has to do with what reputation does or doesn't imply.

Comment: @NickCox Well it does because what confuses other people can confuse me as well. If I can see a bit more clearly into an issue than others, rest assured there is some elbow grease involved and that combination is what garnishes the most reputation points. The obverse, what confuses me, also confuses some other people, and when I work such things out I generally get less increased reputation points, but still substantial reputation, than from "clarifying general confusion."

Comment: Simply going by the fact answering a popular question is much more worthy than answering an actually challenging question goes miles towards understanding what reputation reflects. It's a sign that a person can answer questions that helps the community most. In StackOverflow this is more blatant, often the highest ranked answers on a programming language are utterly basic, but that's where the community concentrates, and these are the questions that help the most members.

Comment: Now, tag badges are a clearer sign towards "statistical prowess", imo.

Comment: One other point that seems to be ignored in the discussion above (except by Firebug recently) is that some areas of statistics and some types of questions are more popular than others. If you happen to be knowledgeable in these popular areas, you will have high reputation without a need for much statistical knowledge. So reputation to a large degree indicates how well in tune one is with the popular fields and question types rather than how good one is in statistics or in explaining statistics.

Comment: And then there are users here with high reputation that know essentially only one thing and just keep promoting it again and again in all their answers (regardless of how relevant or irrelevant they are), and somehow (to my surprise) they still get rewarded relatively nicely (perhaps mainly by new users, but I do not have the data to support this assertion). In conclusion, I would say that no simple measure like reputations points, badges, points per answer, proportion of accepted answers etc. would indicate statistical prowess with much accuracy. All they show is how well you "fit in" at CV.

Comment: @RichardHardy Would you not hire an actuary for insurance rate calculations? Specialization in stats is just like in medicine, engineering, and other fields. Sure, broad knowledge has its uses, and I sympathize with your POV, in fact, I agree entirely, and I am way out of my professional scope of practice on this site and one of those rare birds to publish and review for disciplines in which I hold no formal qualifications. However, not everyone has *deep* understanding, and those who learn by rote and do not leave their comfort zone often do better than us 'generalists' monetarily as well.

Comment: I think @RichardHardy really means what he says; the phenomenon for a just a very small number of users is far more pronounced than a question of specialisation, but to make the point concrete would be indiscreet!  There are examples of users supplying essentially the same answer again and again. If it is really off target the community does deal with it.

Comment: @NickCox A really unpopular PhD student, who did not get hired by his university as an instructor and had very few publications, and who said the same kooky things again and again, was named Albert Einstein. There are still lots of people who love to hate him and his work. People become famous not because they know everything, but because they impact everything. The question here goes to impact, not knowledge.

Comment: Sure, but for every crank who turned out to be Einstein (or Galileo), thousands more really were cranks -- or monomaniacs -- in this case hammer fans to whom everything is a nail.

Comment: From my [answer](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/4462/99274) on a different topic, democracy (as in voting) is a really good at upvoting, and lousy at downvoting. The downvoters are more often more nutcases that the authors whose opinions they dislike. Sure you can find cranks, but for every crank, there are 10 monomaniacs attacking them, and the monomaniacs are not the cranks. Monomaniacs tend to hide themselves in difficult to detect narcissism.

Comment: @Carl How can you remotely psycho-analyse downvoters? Unless they declare themselves as downvoting and explain why, your assertion is just wild speculation.  My comment about cranks etc. is historically well-informed: we can be confident retrospectively that most very odd-looking ideas turn out just to be very odd. There are good reasons for downvoting which the SE system explains; that's not to say that some unknown fraction of downvotes are not for reasons not intended by SE.

Comment: @NickCox How can I? I sympathize with you POV and understand it. [Confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) gives people a false sense of ownership of the truth which makes them very bad scientists, i.e., bad adjudicators of assumptions they do not share. Einstein was regarded as a crank, and I have been as well (for less earth shattering things). Some of this skepticism is healthy, as you are fond of pointing out, and, some of it is not meritorious. Truly new ideas have an uphill battle being accepted;

Comment: @NickCox cont.  relativity, [radioimmunoassay](https://www.chemheritage.org/historical-profile/rosalyn-yalow-and-solomon-a-berson), or my own [variable drug volume theory](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0158798). This latter took ten years to get published, before I found a scientist to review it. A scientist is someone who is prepared to discard all preconceptions in order to explain data, and science is never learned, it is only explored.

Comment: @Carl I am more than happy to agree when we do, but you're not answering my last point, and my fault if I didn't make it clear enough. You said "downvoters are more often more nutcases that the authors whose opinions they dislike": neither the content of that comment nor its tone is helpful or appropriate here in my view.

Comment: @NickCox My apologies with respect to tone, it was excessive. Downvotes are typically given when the downvoter sees a single issue with which he disagrees. A downvote is often a needle in a haystack of considerations, and may have nothing to do with the truth. It takes much more of a scientist to correctly downvote than to upvote. I am not inventing this, this has been looked at.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am interested in seeing that evidence. I am simple-minded: I downvote principally on "doesn't show any research effort" and/or "unclear and not useful"; I freely confess that I sometimes downvote when I think someone is being obnoxious. In the latter case, almost always the case is so severe that a moderator intervenes promptly. Otherwise I would like to know how -- on CV, which is the focus -- one determines which vote is "correct". Downvoting is a matter of judgment at all levels. No independent judgment of which decision is correct seems possible or relevant.

Comment: Correction: the criteria are unclear **or** not useful and votes against obnoxious behaviour are defensible as "not useful".

Comment: @NickCox No argument from me on obnoxious behaviour. However, 1) such activity should be flagged for removal by the moderator. 2) If treated by downvoting, which I would not suggest as such behaviour is intolerable, that would constitute a minority of downvoting. I am not suggesting that downvoting is always incorrect, just that the minority of incorrect downvoting as opposed to commenting is not a corrective, scientific behaviour, and is a real impediment to the propagation of science and improvement of CV.

Comment: I always flag too if I think behaviour is obnoxious. Downvoting is a signal to others "Look at this thread and see if you agree!" and people can dissent (even vote up!). In scanning recent posts if you see multiple downvotes, then you can go to look to see what is going on! Chat is some times used to the same purpose. Sure, this could be denigrated as herd or gang behaviour, but it's not violent and typically nothing happens without a moderator action. It's house-cleaning and in a few senses sordid, but that too is needed in science, e.g. in calling out fraud or plagiarism.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48905/discussion-between-carl-and-nick-cox).

Comment: Thanks for the invitation, but I think I have said too much already.

Comment: `Show 32 more comments`. Really? (Sorry, I had to meta-comment that!)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [the 2016 reputation league page](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/19/year/stats/2016-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=1):

> When your fellow users vote up your questions and answers on a Stack
>   Exchange site, you generate reputation. Reputation is a rough measure
>   of:
>
> - how much the community trusts you
> - your communication skills
> - the quality and relevancy of your questions and answers
>
> These friendly reputation leagues are an informal way of tracking your
>   reputation within the community on a particular Stack Exchange.
>
> Reputation is capped at 200 per day, but remember that bounty awards
>   and accepted answers are immune to this daily reputation cap.

And I concur with that. As I pointed in the comments:

> Simply going by the fact answering a popular question is much more
>   worthy than answering an actually challenging question goes miles
>   towards understanding what reputation reflects. It's a sign that a
>   person can answer questions that helps the community most. In
>   StackOverflow this is more blatant, often the highest ranked answers
>   on a programming language are utterly basic, but that's where the
>   community concentrates, and these are the questions that help the most
>   members

Tag badges sound more like measures of prowess in a specific subject to me.

Comment: Different tags are differently popular. In addition, the typical amount of upvoting per view seems to differ strongly between tags. One might try to compare 2 users w/i the same tag while controlling for the number of views the threads have had since their answer was posted, but this would still measure a mishmash of things (eg, statistical insight, English proficiency, etc).

Comment: @gung True, I didn't think about the popularity of tags (and how they come and go in questions, especially here in CV).

Comment: You can fit a two-way random effect model with tags and people, if you like.